# Cut line shortcut in Visual Studio Code (Ctrl+L in VS) (not delete line!)

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

Visual Studio has by default the shortcut Ctrl+l (cut line). It copies the line where the cursor is to the clipboard and deletes it.

I cannot find it in Visual Studio Code. Is there a way to add it as end user?

(I know there is Ctrl+Shift+K for delete line, which is not the same)

Comment: CMD/Ctrl+X without selection going on

Answer (score 53):

What you are looking for is the *Cut* command:

```
editor.action.clipboardCutAction
```

It cuts (copies to the clipboard then deletes the line) either a selection or the entire line if nothing is selected.
I tested it with vscode 1.23.1

On windows this command is bound to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> as well as to <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd> by default.

Command works this way when *Editor: Empty Selection Clipboard* preference is enabled. It is enabled by default:

```
"editor.emptySelectionClipboard": true
```

Comment: Wow! It is very intuitive - even easier than Ctrl+L. Though it has a defect it copies also the new line character at the end of the line :(. So when one cuts the line and then pastes it, one gets one extra new line ... which has to be deleted most of the time :(

Comment: So the full sequence looks now:
Ctrl+X Ctrl+V Backspace(to get rid of the new line).

Comment: You can combine these commands and bind it to a single shortcut with the [macros extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=geddski.macros).

Comment: Though macros could do it - it is not very nice solution:
Ctrl+X to cut and then Ctrl+Something_Else to paste (run the macros) - but Ctrl+V is what everyone expects for pasting. Thanks anyway!

Comment: This is not working for me in MacOS. `clipboardCutAction` doesn't do anything if no text is selected.

Comment: For MacOS - use the Cmd-X, Cmd-V instead of Ctrl-X

Comment: If you came here hoping to learn the opposite binding, delete but not copy to clipboard, it's `editor.action.deletelines`.

Comment: This is not the same. "Ctrl + L" would expand the cut action to the full lines if partial parts of multiple lines were selected.

Answer (score 5):

I was a able to get the same functionality (i.e., mimicking Sublime Text's 'cut selection' functionality) by doing the following:

1. Added the 'macros' extension by geddski:

[image]

2. Added the following entries to my settings.json file (ctrl+shift+p, "Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)")

```
  "macros": {
    "cutLines": [
        "expandLineSelection",
        "editor.action.clipboardCutAction"
    ]
  }
```

3. Added the following to my settings json file (ctrl+shift+p, "Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts"):

```
  {
    "key": "ctrl+x",
    "command": "macros.cutLines",
    "when": "!editorHasSelection"
  },
```

To get VS Code to recognize the command I had to add uninstall and reinstall the "macros" extension.  I presume adding the entries and then installing it for the first time would produce the same result.

For debugging purposes, here is a screenshot of my keybindings for "Ctrl+x" when I had everything working the way I wanted. Compare yours by typing "Open Keyboard Shortcuts" into the command prompt and searching for "Ctrl+x".

[image]

Comment: Awesome! Thank you! I bound `Ctrl + L` to `editor.action.deleteLines` and `Ctrl + Shift + L` to `macros.cutLines`. A setup I had in VS that I really liked. I will probably be using this plugin a lot.
-
Didn't have any trouble with VS Code recognizing the command, perhaps an update has fixed it.

Comment: Haha, I wrote this like 3 years ago.  It has long since been fixed.

Answer (score 5):

`Shift + Delete` on VS Code cuts the line i.e. copies the line to the clipboard and deletes it.

I am running VS Code on Ubuntu 18.

Edit:
`Ctrl + X` also works the same way.

Comment: for some reason, `keyboard shortcuts` only lists ctrlX, but shiftDelete works too