# Is there any way in VS Code to get IntelliJ's line deletion behaviour?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In IntelliJ (and all the other Jetbrains products sharing the editor component), pressing the Delete Line keybinding without any selection will delete the entire line, and not just the text to the left of the cursor.

Is there any way to get this behaviour in VS Code too?

Answer (score 0):

As per [Cut line shortcut in Visual Studio Code (Ctrl+L in VS) (not delete line!)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50367538/cut-line-shortcut-in-visual-studio-code-ctrll-in-vs-not-delete-line) ...

The `editor.action.clipboardCutAction` keybinding (default in windows Ctrl+x) has this behavior. I just verified that this works in the latest release (1.60).

Comment: it has worked this for years with `Ctrl+X`

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add this to your `keybindings.json`:

```json
{
    ...
    {
        "key": "cmd+backspace",
        "command": "editor.action.deleteLines"
    }
    ...
}
```

Or replacing `cmd` for `ctrl` on windows/linux machines.